# Algorithm for Gif Maker using Bash Script

Tags: bash, image, shell, terminal, gif

I am writing a script that would help me ***convert a set of given PNG or JPG files into a GIF image***. I have started this as my first project in college, so I need help in knowing what exactly should be **the procedure** to carry out this task.
I am using Bash (at an introductory level) and I am quite well versed with algorithms and their understanding.

I would be very thankful if you would tell me just the steps onto how to carry out my project.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `convert` utility.

Documentation: https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php

Comment: Sorry, but then theres nothing I am doing in it. Shouldnt there be an algorithm.

Comment: convert can combine one or more `jpg` or `png` files into a `gif` among other things. Look at this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24014/creating-a-gif-animation-from-png-files